# How can I use an NSDictionary and map my array of strings to each UIViewController class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How can I use an `NSDictionary` and map my array of strings to each `UIViewController` class,  and then use `objectForKey` and get the correct view controller for each key?

I am trying to have each item of my array push to its own view controller.

My array is:

`NSArray *Cities:@["New York", "Chicago", "Miami"];`

and i want the item `@"New York"` to push to `NewYorkViewcontroller` and `@"Chicago"` to `chicagoviewvontroller` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider having a different segue for each item, and in your dictionary store the segue identifier.

However, this will quickly get out of hand if you have more than a few items, in which case you are better off having a generic view controller with custom setup methods rather than doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary* mapping = @{"New York”: [NewYorkViewController class], … };

NSString* chosenCity;

Class vcClass = mapping[chosenCity];

UIViewController* vc = [[vcClass alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
@[@{@"title":@"New York",@"vc_class":[NewYorkViewController class]}, …];
```

Comment: before that would i do nsdictionary *citiesdictionary=?

Comment: and then what would would i put in my didSelectRowAtIndexPath: and cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: why do you need cities dictionary if you already have NSArray - just use it inside your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method to access title and didSelectRow to access class of view controller to present, like: cell.textLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row][@"title"];

Comment: so thats an array and in my didselectrowatindexpath: [self.navigationController pushViewcontroller:??????? animated:YES]; what vc do i put there or do i just put the array.indexpath[row]?

Comment: In didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method: UIViewController *vcToGo = [self.items[@"indexPath.row"][@"vc_class"] alloc] init];

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-code:

```
NSDictionary * myDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: newYorkViewController, chicagoviewcontroller forKeys: Cities[0], Cities[1]];

[self pushViewController: [myDictionary objectForKey:@"New York"] animated:YES];
```